# aspect starange exception during weaving

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I try to use aspect for repeatable actions.

I have following aspect configuration:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class TestInterceptor {

    @Around("execution(public Map<Object, Object> controller.class.ContollerName+.*(..)) && this(self)")
    public Object configureCommonResponse(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, ControllerName self) throws Throwable {
        return pjp.proceed();
    }
}
```

Also I have a controller with methods which I need to modify:

```
@Controller
public class ControllerName {

@RequestMapping("/test")
public Map<Object, Object> test() {
....
}
}
```

However when I try to invoke `test` method I get following exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [springServlet] in context with path [/test] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'controllerName': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.Integer controller.pageSize; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'className' defined in URL [jar:file:/pathToJar.jar!/className/ClassName.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class className.ClassName]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given] with root cause
```

Why does it try to create a subclas for `ClassName` class? I explicitly asked to intercept executions in `controller.class.ContollerName` and subclasses, did not I?

Comment: If I would be in your stead, I would have a look at the compiled class files of `ControllerName`, maybe this gives a hint of whats going on.

Comment: @Ralph, what will I see there? It is ordinary class, there is no compile time weaving.

Comment: oh my falult, I expected that you use compile time waving,

Comment: Not sure if this is still relevant or you even still care, but in the pointcut definition you reference 'ContollerName', while the class is named 'ControllerName'. You're missing an 'r'.